# Create new row after saving a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A user submits a url, this is put into into article.url through the scaffold create method.  I can parse the url like so:

```
def parse_url
  elements = @article.url.split("/")
  if(elements[0] == "http:")
    @home = elements[2] #elements[1] will be an empty string because of the // in the URL
  else
    @home = elements[0]
  end
end
```

What I would prefer to do is to parse the url after the user saves it with the create method and then insert this value into a new row in the database in the article table.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Are you asking how to insert into a database?

Comment: look at the activerecord callbacks, specifically after_save

Comment: Say someone submits http://www.nyt.com/1234 I want to save this value to the db. In addition I want to parse the url to www.nyt.com and then save that value into a new row on the db for the corresponding article_id.

Comment: class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
after_create :clean_url

def clean_url
   elements = self.article.url.split("/")
     if(elements[0] == "http:")
    home = elements[2] #elements[1] will be an empty string because of the // in the URL
      else
    home = elements[0]
     end
   end

So how can I then save this to article.home_page?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use something like the following:

```
class Article
  attr_accessor :unparsed_url

  before_validation_on_save :parse_url

  private

  def parse_url
    return unless unparsed_url

    elements = unparsed_url.split("/")
    if(elements[0] == "http:")
      self.home = elements[2]
    else
      self.home = elements[0]
    end
  end
end
```

You'd use unparsed_url in the Rails forms.  Using a virtual attribute like this will work nicely with form validation.